# reading the library redux by moving it inside src folder of app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have been trying to read the redux library so in order to do this , I first copied the redux from node-modules and moved it inside src .
Another change that I did was in the store.js where I imported redux this way

```
import {createStore ,applyMiddleware} from './redux';/
```

I see that the web-app is working perfectly fine after doing this.However, I have put few console logs inside the redux library but none of them seems to appear in the console.
I have written one console at index.d.ts 
and another in index.js inside src folder of redux and few more.N one seems to be showing up in the console.

Comment: incase logs are under redux library it wont be reflecting since its must have some security concerns to whom logs can be exposed

Comment: Hey so where should I put the logs in order to read the code and debug ?

Comment: are you trying to debug redux lib ? or your piece of code?

Comment: i basically want to do some actions in my app and see corresponding changes in the redux library by reading console logs.

Comment: why dont you use redux dev tools which will show you your application state

Comment: Hey @KOTIOS i am aware of redux-logger but i want to read this library and see how things happen

Comment: oh okay , i m not sure on lib logs can be really exposed to user until you actually build it , try looking into source code if there is any tooggles for logs in redux library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179101/discussion-between-satyajeet-jha-and-kotios).